# MySQl 5.6.28 Error when trying to pass a vatiable to limit in select statement

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Trying to create a stored procedure that take several IN variables which are used in a select statement:

```
   CREATE PROCEDURE getevents
```

(
    mytoday varchar(64),nextWeek varchar(64),lon varchar(64),lat varchar(64),mylimit INT
) 
BEGIN 
SELECT events.Open_All_Year,events.Category as PictureName,events.EventID,events.Title,events.Long_Description,events.Times_Fees,events.Event_Attraction,events.Event_Street1,events.Event_Street2,events.Event_Postcode,events.Event_Town,events.Event_County,events.Latitude_degs, events.Longitude_degs,events.Short_Description, CASE WHEN (opening_dates.Start_Date <= mytoday AND opening_dates.Stop_Date >= mytoday) THEN mytoday ELSE opening_dates.Start_Date END as Start_Date, opening_dates.Stop_Date, ( (ACOS(SIN(lat * PI()/180) * SIN(Latitude_degs * PI()/180) + COS(lat * PI() / 180) * COS(Latitude_degs * PI() / 180) * COS((lon)*PI()/180))*180/PI())*60*1.1515 ) as distance, webID, events.Wifi, events.Dogs, events.Disabled, events.Fee, events.Telephone, events.Email, events.Inactive FROM events,opening_dates where(events.EventID = opening_dates.FKEvent) AND (Review = false) AND (Inactive = 0) AND (((Start_Date <= mytoday) AND (Stop_Date >= mytoday)) OR (Start_Date between mytoday and nextWeek)) ORDER BY distance, Start_Date ASC limit mylimit;
END;

Gives an unhelpful #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 6

Comment: remove the $ - limit mylimit

Comment: tried that, gives a SQL syntax error:#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have unexpanded php variables in your mysql stored procedure call, such as $mylimit or $mytoday. Either you have to expand them when you run the create procedure command, so they become fixed parameters, or you have to create a stored procedure with parameters and you provide the parameters run time, when you call the stored procedure.

Parameters from the query are referred to by their names only, no need to use $ prefix as in php, or enclose them by single quotes to mark a string.

Also, please pay attention how you define the stored procedure, esspecially the use of the delimiter command - see mysql documentation on [defining stored procedures](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-programs-defining.html)

Comment: They are provided at run time, (
        mytoday varchar(64),nextWeek varchar(64),lon varchar(64),lat varchar(64),mylimit INT
    )  sets them as IN variables

To be clear, the issue is in creating the SP, not running it (havent got that far yet)

Comment: i was trying to add the SP by executing SQL. the $ signs were causing the issue - I have added this as a procedure through the phpmyadmin web interface instead, and it took the statement. Thanks for the pointers